# Creating Column Name as Case in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why does this `WHERE` clause not work?

```
WHERE 
    1 = 1
    (CASE WHEN @Datecategory = 'Beginn' THEN [Beginn] ELSE '' END) BETWEEN (@start) AND (@end)
```

I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Because `''` is not a `date(time)`

Comment: Don't use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` anyway, it isn't SARGable. Use proper boolean logic with `AND`s and `OR`s.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised the error reported that; you're missing an `OR` or `AND` after your (redundant) `1 = 1` clause.

Comment: the column name is not date(time) its string.

Comment: If not using case. How else to do it? If the user put an input SQL should chose the particular colum in the WHERe Clause.

Comment: You don't have any AND or OR operator between the first condition (1 = 1) and the second (case when .... ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `CASE` expression at all; just use "good ol'" boolean logic with `AND` and `OR`s and parenthesis:

```sql
WHERE (@Datecategory = 'Beginn'
  AND  [Beginn] >= @start AND [Beginn] <= @End)
   OR @Datecategory != 'Beginn' --If @Datecategory can be NULL then use: OR (@Datecategory != 'Beginn' OR @Datecategory IS NULL)
```

Comment: No, as I mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68527702/creating-column-name-as-case-in-where/68527807?noredirect=1#comment121108029_68527702) it's not SARGable.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean, @petertollfenxx ?

Comment: @petertollfenxx using CASE in the WHERE section works, but it's not recommendable on big tables because the engine won't be able to use indexes to filter quickly your data.

Comment: I got you Marc. Make sense. But why the code of Larnu does not work?

Comment: Again, what does "does not work" mean, @petertollfenxx ... A mechanic can't tell you what might be wrong with your car by being told "it does not work"; it is no different with code. As much as we would like be, the users here are not mind readers.